# MySQL select_for_update() and triggers .. how blocking works?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, database, innodb

I have a row with an integer value, there're many concurrent requests on that row, I want that every read operation to be followed by an update operation (increment), and keep the data consistent, only one request can read->update at the same time.


I've made some research and figured out the select_for_update(), and I also thought of making a trigger on SELECT to increment the value AFTER it's selected, the question is .. Will that work as I'm assuming?


Is the trigger working in parallel or is it consistent this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django `select_for_update` is a wrapper for the `select ... for update` feature present in most common databases (postgres, mysql, oracle...), which basically locks the selected rows against concurrent updates.

[PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)

[MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

You need to wrap the lock into a transaction so the access will be locked until the execution of the transaction ends.

Comment: If I open a transaction using transcation.atomic(), and use select_for_update() inside the transaction.atomic() statement, will the rows be locked until the very last line of the transaction.atomic() block?

Comment: yes, all matched rows will be locked until the end of the transaction block. You can test this behaviour by putting a time sleep into the transaction block and try to update the rows while the execution is still inside the block.